# When user taps on the push notification message, my app launches. How to make the app display the push message in full?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio, push-notification

Good day!

I have successfully sent push notification message to my app on android, and when I tap on the message, it launches my app. May I ask how do I pass intent/bundle to MainActivity from the push notification so that when the app is launched, it can display the push notification message in full within the app? Thank you very much!

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Explicitly specify that GcmMessageHandler will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());

    showNotification(context, intent);

    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}

private void showNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    String title = intent.getExtras().getString("nTitle");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("nMessage");

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);

    Notification notification = mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.face)
            .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.wallet_holo_blue_light))
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.fuckya))
            .setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentText(message).build();

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)     context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Regards,
Lorkh

Comment: Please post code which handles push notification in your android app

Comment: when you build your notification you should specify an intent to launch when the notification is clicked. Add some extras in this intent and handle them when launching app.

Comment: I've tried commenting the line

startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

but the app still launches when the notification message is tapped. I thought app launching when push is tapped is a default android action...

Answer (score 0):

Replace to:

```
Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
String title = intent.getExtras().getString("nTitle");
String message = intent.getExtras().getString("nMessage");
mainActivityIntent.putExtra("nTitle", title);
mainActivityIntent.putExtra("nMessage",message);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainActivityIntent), 0);
```

And retrieve this values inside your MainActivity via `getIntent()`;